# problem with oracle connection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have a Windows XP  machine used to create .Net applications with VS 2008.

I want to connect to a remote network server (using Windows xp) that is running an Oracle 10g database.

I am using the code below (with the first connection string) to connect directly to a version of 10g that is running on the same machine with no problems, however when I try to connect to the network machine, it actually crashes my application.

I have tried several variations of connection strings as I feel that I must be making a syntax error somewhere.

What concerns me is that I have dual try/catch statements in the application and I do not understand why it simply does not refuse the connection and report the error.

I suppose the real question is 'what is the correct syntax for the connection string'....or WHATEVER the hell I am doing wrong.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
//Class Variables
string CONNSTR = "Server=192.168.0.1:1521;User ID=zahid;Password=abc123;";


public Oracle()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

//Methods
private void TestMyOracleConnection()
{
  OracleConnection Conn = new OracleConnection(CONNSTR);
  try
  {
    Conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Oracle Connection Established", "Success");
  }
  catch (OracleException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Oracle Connection Failed!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Oracle Connection Failed!");
  }
  finally
  {
    Conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Oracle Connection Closed", "Success");
  }
}

private void buttonTestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TestMyOracleConnection();
}
```

Comment: What does 'I have dual try/catch statements' mean? There's only one try block here, with several lines not covered by it.  When it crashes your application, does it output a stack trace?  What does it say?

Comment: It's possible that it crashes in native code, `try..catch` might not be able to catch it. Have you tried other Oracle Client versions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), you can try a connection string such as the following (taken from a `web.config`):

```
<add name="OdpConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xe;User Id=some_user;Password=some_password; Promotable Transaction=local"
     providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

You can read this connection string from the web.config in your code using something like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OdpConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

It's a good practice to avoid putting connection strings directly in code, since to change them requires a re-compile. By putting them in a config file, such as `web.config` or `app.config`, you can change them without having to re-compile your library or exe.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like:

connection string:

```
Data Source=DBNAME;User ID=zahid;Password= abc123;Persist Security Info=True;Unicode=True;
```

Now look in the tnsname.ora file on your PC. It will be somewhere under your local Oracle Client installation. You're looking for something like:

```
DBNAME =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = OracleServerName)(PORT = 1510))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = OracleServerName)(PORT = 1514))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = DBNAME)
    )
  )
```

You're looking to replace `DBNAME` and `OracleServerName` with your own. Don't forget, `DBNAME` is the name of the main database, not one of the schemas (the entity with all the tables and procedures, etc) under it.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
  {
    Conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Oracle Connection Established", "Success");
  }
  catch (OracleException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Oracle Connection Failed!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Oracle Connection Failed!");
  }
  finally
  {
    Conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Oracle Connection Closed", "Success");
  }
```

You have pottential problem here: if conn.Open() fails (so connection is not opened) in finally you call conn.close(), but connection isn't opened - so it also fails, but it is now outside try catch. You need check for

```
if (Conn!=null && Conn.IsOpen())
  Conn.Close();
```

---

Connection string for oracle:
Data Source=TORCL;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

[More here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)